# How to generate new JWT token from old token in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionEntryPoint());
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(""/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security" 
                        "/webjars/**", "/users/social-sign-up", "client/**","/actuator/**",
                        "/instances","/assets/**","/home","/tables","/resources/**","/static/**",
                        "/css/**","/js/**","/scss/**","/templates").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_VERIFY_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), applicationUserRepository))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security

                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }



}
```

Then I have a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` like this

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())).build()
                    .verify(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then I have `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` like this

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {

            ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
            System.err.println("Creds " + creds.getUsername() + ", " + creds.getPassword());

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                    creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = JWT.create().withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME)).sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        String userName = ((User)auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        ApplicationUser au= applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(userName);
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(au);
        res.getWriter().write(json);
        res.getWriter().flush();
        res.getWriter().close();



    }
}
```

I am able to generate JWT token in HEADER. Like this

```
Authorization →Bearer awgaagarbrqe342tewrbwrewh.23tebvre34h4wbseb43qberqbqv.23gwrwvw4hw5445jmet76e-gqgqggq323t9003qgnibqp2389bvqp9q83bv9
```

What I am trying to achieve is whenever the token gets expired, the client sending the latest expired token will get a new token based on the token they have sent.
So my question is, how do I generate a refresh token or a mechanism that will take the old expired token and generate a new token?

Comment: Implement a way to generate a new token from your Identity Provider (e.g. Keycloak, ..) and always get a new one when the old one is expired. This can be done through the API of your Provider or using a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would weaken the security of the application since new tokens can be retrieved from expired ones(invalid tokens). So you should try not to do it.

If you have to do it, keep a table in the db with the tokens and their validity, then when you get an invalid jwt token exception go to db check for the said token and see when it was expired. If it was 5 mins ago then you could probably renew it otherwise don't.